# error on call to php file from javascript [HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently 807ms]

Tags: php, javascript, http-status-code-301

I've a javascript code that calls a php file and receives the output. My javascript code is

```
 function properties(location) {

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        xmlHttpRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if(window.ActiveXObject)
        xmlHttpRequest=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlHttpRequest.open('GET','myfile.php?region='+region,true);
    xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState==4)    
          alert(xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttpRequest.send();
  }
```

The code works well on localhost and I receive the output, but when I try it on live server, it is not working, and in the console of browser it is showing the following message

```
[14:36:20.350] GET http://mysite.com/myfile.php?region=South [HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently 807ms]
```

and it is also giving me another web url, any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Open your web browser and do this.

Try URL with "www." and check if it redirects to non-www. As well try without "www." and check for redirect.

After you see final location edit url location in your code.

You might also check .htaccess file on server to see if it has any redirects.

Comment: I've checked it with www. and it is redirected to  website.com instead of www.website.com. In my code I've website.com, but it is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlHttpRequest.open('GET','myfile.php?region='+region,true);
```

Here you give the complete path or correct relative url.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your base url before send to server

```
var baseurl = 'yoursite.com';
xmlHttpRequest.open('GET',baseurl+'myfile.php?region='+region,true);
```

Comment: check in firebug, whether request being sent to server or not?

Comment: In firebug I've the the link I mentioned above with the 301 error, it is displayed red.